# php back navigation issue

Tags: php, navigation

I am building a php web app and I am having some trouble with the navigation. It seems the user have to hit back twice  to get past one of my apparent traps. . .

Consider this situation. The user wants to upload a file with a description, so he hits upload and gets directed to the upload.php page. He fills out the form and submits the form to uploader.php. Uploader.php redirects him back to upload.php?yay=true. 
From here, he needs to hit back twice to get back to the page where he hit the upload button. 
Is there a clever way to keep track of which page he originally came from (this case, 2 pages back) or do i need to keep his navigation story in say the session variable?

I could also just redirect to the page from where the user hit the upload button, but this means that the back button will take him to the fileupload.php page instead of the page previously to the one that had the upload button.

Any help appriciated!

Comment: Why not just keep the referring URL in the URL for upload page? Upload.php?ref=URL and keep it in all links and use it to send the user back at the end?

Comment: If the page you would like to redirect back to is always the same, then you could simply just override your "back" button and make it link to that page. If not, then you'll need to store the "referer" page in either a session or GET variable. You could also use e.g. javascript and use the `history.go(-2)` code.. It depends on your app and your code structure whether you want to use any of these, or find something more reliable and secure

Answer (score 1):

Simple after doing upload stuff, justt redirect him to the original page like

```
// do the upload stuff
header('location:the_page_name.php');//the page where user originaly came from
```

Comment: i tried that but if i hit the back button after the redirect, i get back to the fileupload.php page, somewhat making the redirect redundent. 

Thanks for the aweser though =)

Comment: set a variable say $a=1 in the 1st page and then only if $a=1 do redirection. In your next page you can increment $a. That way the redudant redirection wont happen